# Phonegap developer app error

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing an app using phonegap and their developer app to help me along the way.  However, I cannot connect to the server after running the command
    `cordova serve`
from the root directory.  It serves it up on port 8000 (by default) and I set a static IP address on my macbook to be 10.0.0.129.  So when I enter 10.0.0.129:8000 into the "Server Address" field in the developer app I get 'Error!' followed by 'Timeout!'

Could someone please provide an explanation of this and how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a .cordova directory in your project directory, then use `phonegap serve`, because `cordova serve` doesn't work with the app.